# How can a launcher .desktop file be added to the Unity7 Launcher from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, unity, launcher, .desktop

I have a setup script that configures a new Ubuntu installation just the way I like it. I want to add `.desktop` launchers to the Unity7 Launcher in this script (rather than dragging and dropping them to the Launcher). How can this be done?